# Google Login Error - E/Databuffer

Tags: android

Any help would be appreciated :)

I have integrated google login to my codes, It was working perfect since last 12 days. Suddenly it stopped signing in from Google when I am clicking on Sign in, It loads and then fails.

Error -

```
05-14 20:43:33.731 28380-28387/? E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@d51caac)
```

I dont know what is the issue exactly. Why this came suddenly after everything was going perfect. I didnt made any changes in code even.
Can anyone help me out

Comment: There is a databuffer you haven't released

Comment: I am new to Android, is there any way to release such